# Can't click on the ListItem of SectionList while having focus in TextInput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

**Problem:** I have a page with a TextInput and a SectionList. When I focus on TextInput and then click on the ListItem in the SectionList - it only hides the keyboard but does not navigate to SecondPage, which it should do onPress, as you can see below. If a TextInput is unfocused - everything works fine.

**Desired behavior:** While focusing on the TextInput, if I click on a ListItem - it should navigate me to the SecondPage.

**Questions:**
1. Is something wrong with my code or that's a normal behavior with SectionList?
2. Is there a way to achieve the desired behavior?

**Code:**

SectionList + TextInput component

```
const ds = [
        { data: [ {word: 'BMW'}, {word: 'Mercedez'}, {word: 'Tesla'}], title: 'Cars' },
        { data: [{word: 'Finland'}, {word: 'USA'}, {word: 'Somalia'}], title: 'Countries' },
        { data: [{word: 'Water'}, {word: 'Coke'}, {word: 'Tea'}], title: 'Liquids' },
    ];

class FirstPage extends React.Component {

render() {
    return ( 
        <View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TextInput 
                onChangeText={(v) => this.setState({ text: v})}
                style={{ borderWidth: 1, flex: 1 }}
                value={this.state.text}
            />
        </View>
            <SectionList
                    renderItem={({ item }) => <ListItem word={item.word} navigation={this.props.navigation} />}
                    renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => <ListItem word={section.title} section/>}
                    sections={ds}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.word}
                />
        </View>
            );
}
}
```

ListItem component

```
render() {
        const { navigation, section, word } = this.props;
        const { letterStyle, noteStyle, sectionStyle, termStyle } = styles;
        if (section)    
        {       
            return (
            <TouchableOpacity>            
                <View>
                    <CardSection style={sectionStyle}>
                        <Text style={letterStyle}>{word}</Text>
                    </CardSection>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        }
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SecondPage')} 
            >
                <View>
                    <CardSection style={sectionStyle}>
                        <Text numberOfLines={1} style={termStyle}>{word}</Text>
                    </CardSection>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            );
    }
```

Comment: This solution works for SectionLists as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307853/touchableopacity-unclickable-while-textinput-has-focus/36332283#36332283
Modified the selected answer at this link to reflect the successful application of the solution for SectionLists.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:

```
onMenuPress(item){
   console.log(item);
   this.props.navigation.navigate("some_route");
}

render() {
.....some code
    <ListItem onPress={(item) => this.onMenuPress(item)}>
....more code
}
```

Remember that bind the onMenuPress method on constructor, like this:

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.onMenuPress = this.onMenuPress.bind(this);
}
```

Works for me.